# Repository access denied. access via a deployment key is read-only

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket, ssh-keys

After successfully cloning my repo from heroku and added another remote

```
1/ git clone git@heroku.com:[APP].git
2/ git remote add bitbucket ssh://git@bitbucket.org/[ACCOUNT]/[REPO].git
3/ git push bitbucket master
```

I am still getting this error after running line (3) or using SourceTree

```
conq: repository access denied. access via a deployment key is read-only.
```

First I don't understand what this message means in practice. And that's shame.

I did create ssh key pair and added to heroku :

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa 
heroku keys:add ./id_rsa.pub
```

I also added my key in deployment keys section in BitBucket. But I must be missing something. This question is not out of laziness, I have been reading various docs including BitBuckets guides. But it still don't get around this issue.

This post is related to [Can I import my heroku git repo into bitbuket? and how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13300068/can-i-import-my-heroku-git-repo-into-bitbuket-and-how/)

ADDITIONAL FACTS:

```
ssh -T hg@bitbucket.org
conq: authenticated via a deploy key.

You can use git or hg to connect to Bitbucket. Shell access is disabled.


$ ssh -v git@bitbucket.org
OpenSSH_5.6p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/joel/.ssh/config
debug1: Applying options for bitbucket.org
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to bitbucket.org [207.223.240.181] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/joel/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /Users/joel/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.6
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host 'bitbucket.org' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/joel/.ssh/known_hosts:5
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/joel/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Remote: Forced command: conq deploykey:13907
debug1: Remote: Port forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: X11 forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Agent forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Pty allocation disabled.
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Remote: Forced command: conq deploykey:13907
debug1: Remote: Port forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: X11 forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Agent forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Pty allocation disabled.
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to bitbucket.org ([207.223.240.181]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LC_CTYPE = UTF-8
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
```

Looks like all is fine.

Comment: Adding a SSH key instead of Deployment key worked for me

Comment: Remember to vote up both question and answers. Cheers!!

Answer (score 726, accepted):

First confusion on my side was about where exactly to set **SSH Keys** in BitBucket.

I am new to BitBucket and I was setting a **Deployment Key** which gives *read-access* only.

So make sure you are setting your `rsa pub key` in your **BitBucket Account Settings**.

Click your BitBucket avatar and select **Bitbucket Settings**(<del>Manage account</del>). There you'll be able to set **SSH Keys**.

I simply deleted the **Deployment Key**, I don't need any for now. And it worked

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is exactly the same thing I was missing. I added a deployment key instead of an SSH Key.

Comment: I'm facing the exact same problem and your solution didn't fix. I have the same settings, the same symptoms and the same attempted fix. No dice. Could it just be a bug with BitBucket?

Comment: Yes! Thank you for your answer. Atlassian should really make it clearer in their documention.

Comment: Yes that ssh key menu is well hidden in Bitbucket!

Comment: Struggled with this for 30 minutes before found your answer, thank you very much

Comment: Your solutions saves me much time. I spent time to solve that. Thanks.
Need to be remembered that we have two places for setting SSH keys. Here we should add a SSH key in the global settings, not for each project/repository.

Comment: if you do this then anyone who has access to your site can access all your git repository.

Comment: Also it should be noted that you can't have two of the same key in two places.  If you want to re-use the key you already generated, you have to delete the deploy key first, then add the account key.  Otherwise it returns an error.

Comment: The interface has changed a bit, the flow is now: 'Bitbucket avatar' > settings > Security: SSH keys

Comment: Thanks a lot .. I was also struggling with this issue.  Unfortunately bitbucket has not documented this clearly anywhere.  The first impulse for any new user would be to add the ssh key under his project.

Comment: Just a note: you'll have first to delete the deployment key, otherwise you won't be able to add the same key in your profile...

Comment: This explains it better than I've seen it elsewhere but my resolution came from removing the integration I was using with cloud9.io.  There was a feature to integrate with bitbucket.  I actually had bitbucket set up properly, but it was only after I unchecked the 'integrate with bitbucket' option that I the RSA key was added.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You're right. I added it in a git repository instead of the bitbucket settings so it's not working. :p

Answer (score 64):

Now the SSH option is under the security settings

Click Your Avatar --> Bitbucket Settings --> SSH Key --> Add Key

Paste your public key

Comment: Thank you. I just want to describe my case. I added my public key in the repository settings instead of in my Bitbucket account keys. So I deleted the key in repository and added it in my profile settings in order to get it working.

Answer (score 18):

you need to add your key to your profile and **NOT** to a specific repository.
follow this:
https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/How-do-I-add-an-SSH-key-as-opposed-to-a-deployment-keys/qaq-p/413373

Comment: this was my case Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

Deployment keys are read only. To enable write access you need to:

- Remove this deployment key from your repository settings. You won't be able to write to this repo with this key anyway.
- Go to "Avatar -> Settings -> SSH Keys" and add the same key
- Now try to push to remove branch

You were able to write to repositories before but this is a change in BitBucket where you're no longer able to write with deploy key.

Comment: Thanks this worked for me after pulling hair for a long

Answer (score 10):

'Deployment Key' is only for Read Only access. Following is a good way to work through this.

- Create an SSH key and add it to BitBucket (User Avatar -> Bitbucket Setting-> SSH keys)
- ~/.ssh/known_hosts
- ssh-add -D (Remove keys loaded to SSH agent)
- ssh-add ~/.ssh/your_private_key_for_bitbucket
- ssh git@bitbucket.org -Tv (Verify that your key is getting used to connect to bitbucket)
- git push 'remote name' 'branch name'

Answer (score 9):

You have to delete the deployment key first if you are going to add the same key under Manage Account SSH Key.

Comment: Deleting the deploy key gives me `Someone has already registered this as a deploy key.`

Comment: Be clear that you should add the shh public key under the BITBUCKET SETTINGS (as in for the full BB account) NOT and I repeat NOT under the individual Repo Settings. If you added a key under the repo settings that is why you are getting these errors.

Answer (score 9):

TLDR:  ssh-add ~/.ssh/yourkey

I've just worked through this problem.

And none of the other answers helped.

I did have a ./ssh/config with all the right stuff, also an earlier repository working fine (same bitbucket account, same key). Then I generated a deploy_key, and after that created a new repository.

After that could not clone the new repo.

I wish I knew how/why ssh agent was messing this up, but adding the key solved it. I mean adding the key in my local Ubuntu, not in bitbucket admin. The command is just

```
    ~/.ssh$ ssh-add myregualrkey
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Excellent. This was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I don't understand what you did.

Comment: yeah for everyone adding the -A you have to actually add the key first.

Answer (score 5):

I had this happen when I was trying to use a deployment key because that is exactly what I wanted.

I could connect via `ssh -T git@bitbucket.org` and it would tell me I had access to read the repository I wanted, but `git clone` would fail.

Clearing out `~/.ssh/known_hosts`, generating a new key via `ssh-keygen`, adding that new key to bitbucket, and retrying fixed it for me.

Answer (score 4):

I would like to re-emphasize the following:

- You might have added the SSH key to **your repository** (e.g. ExampleRepo), but this is **NOT where the SSH key goes**.
- It is meant to go into **YOUR PROFILE**. **This is the small avatar on the bottom left corner of the screen.** Here, you'll find a *different* place to put your SSH Keys (under Security) > then you add the key here instead.
- If you accidentally put your SSH key into the repository (as opposed to your account), then delete the one in the repository.

Took me ages to realise, somehow even after reading the answers here it didn't click.

Answer (score 3):

First choose or create the key you want to use for pushing to Bitbucket. Let's say its public key is at `~/.ssh/bitbucket.pub`

- Add your public key to Bitbucket by logging in and going to your public profile, settings, ssh-key, add key.
- Configure ssh to use that key when communicating with Bitbucket. E.g. in Linux add to `~/.ssh/config`:

```
    Host bitbucket.org
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/bitbucket
```

Answer (score 2):

Recently I faced the same issue. I got the following error:

**repository access denied. access via a deployment key is read-only.**

You can have two kinds of SSH keys:

1. **For your entire account** which will work for all repositories
2. **Per repository SSH key** which can only be used for that specific repository.

I simply removed my repository SSH key and added a new SSH key to my account and it worked well.

I hope it helps someone. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue Kabir Sarin had. The solution was to clone the repo via SSH, instead of using the https URL.
so this is what helped me, and hopefully others:

```
    git clone git@bitbucket.org:{accountName}/{repoName}.git
```

Answer (score 1):

> Two step process to be able to push pull
>   
> Step1: Generate ssh key(public and private) on mac
> Step2: Put private key in mac and public key in git website
> below detailed steps are for mac users

**Step 1: Generating keys**

1. (make sure you have git installed)https://git-scm.com/download/mac
2. open terminal and type `ssh-keygen` this will prompt you to enter storage location for key, you may type `/Users/[machinename]/.ssh/[keyname]`
3. Next it will ask for passphrase, you can either leave it blank by pressing enter or enter some keyword to be entered again at next prompt
4. This will have created two keys for you, private and public, with name [keyname] and [keyname].pub

**Step2:pushing keys to appropriate locations[mac and remote accounts i.e Github, bitbucket, gitlab etc ]**

1. Type `ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/[keyname]` in terminal to add your private key to the mac
2. Type `pbcopy < ~/.ssh/[keyname].pub` to copy public key to clipboard
3. Open account settings on your respective git website and go to add key, there paste the public key copied above

> Done, now you can push pull.

Comment: To those who have downvoted, I was struggling whole day and i could not find any answer directly resolving my problem, and the steps mentioned here directly resolves them and they are generic. Anyways

Answer (score 1):

Steps:

1. Create ssh keys on source server

   `ssh-keygen`
2. Cat and copy id_rsa.pub located under ~./ssh directory
3. Go to Bitbucket, if you have already set the access keys for repository(s) then delete existing public key(s)
4. Go to Bitbucket avatar> Bitbucket settings> SSH Keys (under Security, left pane)> Click on 'Add Keys'> paste the public key.
5. Check if it works by running below command on the source server

   `git remote show origin`
6. For fetch and push from the source server, if the protocol is 'https' then you have to change it to 'git+ssh' by running below command

   `git remote set-url origin git+ssh://<bitbucketaccount>@bitbucket.org/<accountname>/repo.git`
7. Check if you can do push to the repo.

Done!

Comment: what's the point when the right answer has been given already 3 or 4 times? why not trying to answer a question that has still no answer.

Comment: Thank you for the kind advice.

Answer (score 0):

All you need - add another key and use it.

As i've found first key - always Deployment Key.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it doesn't work because you manually set another key for bitbucket in `~/.ssh/config`.

Answer (score -3):

for this error : conq: repository access denied. access via a deployment key is read-only.

I change the name of my key, example

```
cd /home/try/.ssh/
mv try id_rsa
mv try.pub id_rsa.pub
```

I work on my own key on bitbucket