# Push to BitBucket from SourceTree

Tags: bitbucket, git-push, atlassian-sourcetree

I am new with BitBucket and SourceTree and I try to push my Rep. in SourceTree for windows with Git to BitBucket but it gives me this error:

```
conq: repository access denied. access via a deployment key is read-only.

fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I set a deployment key in BitBucket by my public key and the ssh key agent is running with my private key. I have owner access right. 
I think I missed a configuration that results in this error, any suggestion?

Comment: I found the reason for that. The ssh key in the user account (not the deployment key) must be loaded **solely** in the ssh agent, otherwise (not added or deployment key is added as well) it will give this error.

Answer (score 8):

Make sure you're not adding the SSH key under "Deployment Key" in your Bitbucket repository's settings. What you need to do is add the SSH key under "Manage Account" (Click your Avatar)> "SSH Keys". It's explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13306435/repository-access-denied-access-via-a-deployment-key-is-read-only/13309843#13309843)

Comment: Thanks from the bottom of my heart. It works for me. I spent a lot of time to solve that.

Comment: Thank you so much for this one. Common sense will prevail! +1

Comment: Is there a solution with register SSH key under "Deployment Key"?
I want use a key within a repo. Not all repos.

Answer (score 0):

Don't create deployment key, go to manage account and click ssh keys then add your key