# How to push a local repo to bitbucket?

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket, ssh-keys, atlassian-sourcetree

I have my repo online at bitbucket, I have created the ssh key using:

```
ssh-keygen
```

And I've used the resulted key as a deployment key for the online repo.
Then, at source-tree I have added the generated key, but when I push the repo, I get this error:

```
Pushing to git@bitbucket.org:xxxxx/xxxxxx.git

Permission denied (publickey).

fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.




Completed with errors, see above.
```

So, what is still missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13309843/6309), setting a "deployment key" would give you read-only access only: a push would never work.

You need to add your public key ($HOME/.ssh/id_rsa) to your BitBucket account.
See "[How to install a public key on your Bitbucket account](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/How+to+install+a+public+key+on+your+Bitbucket+account)"

Comment: I although I've created a specific public key, only the key shown by cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub has worked so, why I can't just add any public key?