# When I try git clone, occur Access denied on sourcetree

Tags: git, github, ssh

I use sourcetree, 
when I need git clone, try use sourcetree. 
my url `ssh://git@192.168.3.98:/mydirectory/111.git`

but occur This is not a valid source path / URL 
I check detail.

```
Command: git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false ls-remote
ssh://git@192.168.3.98:/var/www/git.repos/git.src/blackeye/iosplayer.git
Output: 
Error: Access denied
Access denied
Access denied
Access denied
Access denied
FATAL ERROR: Server sent disconnect message
type 2 (protocol error):
"Too many authentication failures for git"
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

and I search google.
it may ssh client configuration problem, and set mercurial and set git .

I set SSH Client Configuration.
set ssh key, ssh client putty plink.

and mercurial and git always update

how to fix this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Repository access denied. access via a deployment key is read-only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13306435/repository-access-denied-access-via-a-deployment-key-is-read-only)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check at least if the remote server does authenticate you:

```
ssh -Tv git@192.168.3.9
```

That is: is your `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` public key published on the remote server side (in `~git/.ssh/authorized_keys`)

And does your private key has a passphrase associated to it or not?

Check also if `/mydirectory/111.git` does exist on the remote server: this is an absolute path (as opposed to `git@...:mydirectory/111.git`, which would mean `~git/mydirectory/111.git`)