# bitbucket git repository access denied for additional ssh key

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket

I can not push or clone my repositories using ssh. I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.
I read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13309843/2916247) and followed the official [tutorial](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-additional-ssh-keys-271943168.html#) but still I cannot access my repository in BitBucket.

1. I create a new repo on BitBucket.
2. I create an additional ssh-key following the [tutorial](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-additional-ssh-keys-271943168.html#).
3. Then I add all development keys to my account and not for Deployment.
4. I clone the repo using the command:

   ```
   git clone ssh://**localuser**@bitbucket.org/**repoUser**/repo.git
   ```

   and I get this answer:

> Cloning into 'countingsystemv5'... repository access denied.
> deployment key is not associated with the requested repository. fatal:
> Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
> exists.

Comment: Can you double check that the key your client is offering is the one associated with your account? You should be able to see that by running "ssh -v git@bitbucket.org".

Comment: @janos the path of my public key (.pub) is ~/.ssh/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Repository access denied. access via a deployment key is read-only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13306435/repository-access-denied-access-via-a-deployment-key-is-read-only)