# Tow remote in my git config, ionic and bitbucket

Tags: git, ionic-framework, bitbucket, push

I work with ionic, in my git config, I have tow remote, with "git remote -v", I obtain:

```
    |ionic|git@git.ionicjs.com:locoapp/loco.git (fetch)|
|---|---|
|ionic|git@git.ionicjs.com:locoapp/loco.git (push)|
|origin|git@bitbucket.org:teamlocoapp/locoapp.git (fetch)|
|origin|git@bitbucket.org:teamlocoapp/locoapp.git (push)|
```

When I push, modificactions are correctly send to my ionic repo :

```
    ➜  loco git:(master) git push
Counting objects: 2, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (2/2), 258 bytes | 258.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 2 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Received:
remote:     Branch:   master
remote:     Commit Sha:   58258590...
remote:     Commit Msg:   Add test file
remote:  Checking for previous builds...
remote:  New commit or branch detected triggering new build view build log here:
remote:  https://dashboard.ionicjs.com/app/f2a...
To git.ionicjs.com:locoapp/loco.git
   e528045..5825859  master -> master
```

But if I try to push on my bitbucket repo, I have this error :

```
    repository access denied. access via a deployment key is read-only.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

If I clone only ionic repo or bitbucket repo it works fine, but if I have tow remote in my config, only bitbucket works.

Anyone has an idea ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Repository access denied. access via a deployment key is read-only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13306435/repository-access-denied-access-via-a-deployment-key-is-read-only)

Comment: This is not related to the fact you have two remotes, but only the fact you have permission issue with bitbucket's repo.